# How to use chaining in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, python-itertools, chaining

I have a dataframe called `Incito`and in `Supplier Inv No`column of that data frame consists of comma separated values. I need to recreate the data frame by appropriately repeating those comma separated values using pyspark.I am using following python code for that.Can I convert this into pyspark?Is it possible via pyspark?

```
from itertools import chain
def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split(',')))
incito['Supplier Inv No'] = incito['Supplier Inv No'].astype(str)

# calculate lengths of splits
lens = incito['Supplier Inv No'].str.split(',').map(len)

# create new dataframe, repeating or chaining as appropriate
dfnew = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier Inv No': chainer(incito['Supplier Inv No']),
                      'Forwarder': np.repeat(incito['Forwarder'], lens),
                      'Mode': np.repeat(incito['Mode'], lens),
                      'File No': np.repeat(incito['File No'], lens),
                      'ETD': np.repeat(incito['ETD'], lens),
                      'Flight No': np.repeat(incito['Flight No'], lens),
                      'Shipped Country': np.repeat(incito['Shipped Country'], lens),
                      'Port': np.repeat(incito['Port'], lens),
                      'Delivered_Country': np.repeat(incito['Delivered_Country'], lens),
                      'AirWeight': np.repeat(incito['AirWeight'], lens),
                      'FREIGHT CHARGE': np.repeat(incito['FREIGHT CHARGE'], lens)})
```

This is what I tried in pyspark.But I am not getting the expected outcome.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("appName").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(dfnew)


exploded = ddf.withColumn('d', F.explode("Supplier Inv No"))
exploded.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, questions have to come with a least a bit of try. Please provide what you have tried sofar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using [`repeat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.repeat)?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('ABCD',),
        ('EFGH',),
    ])
    .toDF(['col_a'])
)

(df
    .withColumn('col_b', F.repeat(F.col('col_a'), 2))
    .withColumn('col_c', F.repeat(F.lit('X'), 10))
    .show()
)
# +-----+--------+----------+
# |col_a|   col_b|     col_c|
# +-----+--------+----------+
# | ABCD|ABCDABCD|XXXXXXXXXX|
# | EFGH|EFGHEFGH|XXXXXXXXXX|
# +-----+--------+----------+
```